# Cypress me retorna para a tela de Login após submeter o formulário

Tags: login, automatização, cypress

Olá.
Estou testando uma aplicação de um cliente, até 2 dias atrás estava tudo ok.

Porém após uma atualização o seguinte acontece  :

Mesmo colocando E-Mail e Senha corretos, após clicar no botão LOGIN o Cypress recarrega a página de Login quebrando o teste.

OBS - Isso ocorre também com o Selenium + JAVA.
OBS 2 - O Console não mostra erro algum, todos os status = 200.
OBS 3 - Manualmente funciona.

```
 preencherFormularioLogin(){
        cy.get(Elements.email_Field)
           type('E');
        cy.get(Elements.password_Field)
            .type('123456');
        cy.get(Elements.button_login)
            .click();
            
        
        cy.wait(3000);
```

Tentei usar o Selenium + Java porém o erro ainda ocorre

Comment: Uma dúvida: a atualização foi no SEU código (lado do cliente) ou no lado do servidor, que você não controla?

Comment: Cesar, foi no servidor do cliente. Temos uma equipe que cuida do back end também, porém disseram nao mexer em nada comprometedor....Tanto que a API está retornanso cód 200 em tudo.

Comment: Eu fiz essas perguntas pra que você atualize sua pergunta lá em cima, porque são detalhes importantes, ok? Infelizmente, não sou eu que vou poder responder.